# Delete a Jenkins Build via GUI

Tags: jenkins, build, task

How can I delete a build from the Jenkins GUI? I know that I can delete the directory from the 'jobs' folder, but I want to do it from the GUI. Is it also possible to delete multiple builds?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you go into the build you want to delete and if you have the permissions to delete, then you will see on the upper right corner a button "Delete this build".

Comment: Thank you, and there is a way to delete a group of builds?

Comment: Not easily that I'm aware of.

Comment: Purge Build Queue Plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Purge+Build+Queue+Plugin

Comment: Do you know which is the permission to delete a build?

Answer (score 6):

To delete any job from Gui,Go to your job and on left side,click on delete project.

Answer (score 5):

For deleting the entire build history you can do this:

Given your Hudson job is named FooBar,

- rename FooBar to FooBar-Copy
- create a new job named FooBar, using 'Copy existing job' option, from FooBar-Copy
- delete FooBar-Copy

Source: http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Possible-to-remove-all-build-data-and-reset-build-1-td1458487.html

Answer (score 5):

To delete the project itself, "Delete Project" in the left sidebar after clicking on the job.

[image: Delete Project]

Answer (score 1):

Go to project which you want to delete, in upper left frame, you can see delete (maven, if it is maven project) project.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a maven project then in the left side panel, you can see the option as delete maven project. If this is a git or other project then in the job dashboard just right the of the job name you will find an arrow mark dropdown which one option delete the organization. click on that and your job will be deleted.