# Jenkins v2.176.1 how to remove single build from history using UI

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-cli

There are two sides to this question:

Side 1:

How do I remove a *specific* build from the build history (not just "old builds" or "builds that meet parameter X") using the GUI?  The reason I ask for the GUI is because I don't know how to use Jenkins from the command line, otherwise I'd try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562381/remove-jenkins-builds-by-name) SO answer (tangent: tutorial for Jenkins CLI?).

Side 2:

How can I run a build such that it doesn't appear in the build history?  A 'debugging' build?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a Jenkins Build via GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995079/delete-a-jenkins-build-via-gui)

Comment: I don't know -- I was laid off, and no longer have access to the server that was running the build.